# AEC ios multiple audio unit graphs

Tags: ios, core-audio, audiounit, aec

Would acoustic echo cancelation work if I setup different audio unit graphs ( one graph with only input enabled, and 'n' graphs with only output enabled )?

Each graph would rely solely in the voice processing io audio unit.

Thanks a lot,
Daniel

Answer (score 2):

You are only allowed one remoteIO per app on iOS.  So I believe the n outputs scenario isn't possible.  You can, however, use one graph, split the input to multiple nodes, then mix them back in with a mixer connected to the output.